# Can't trigger a click event within my Firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox plugin and I'm trying to trigger some click events. When I execute this from the Firefox console it seems to work:

```
$( ".next" ).trigger( "click" );
```

or

```
var theNode = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].click();
```

But when I use them within my plugin, the clock event is not being triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `console.log($( ".next" ));` what do you get?

Comment: @Sergio I think I can’t log using console.debug(object) in a Firefox Extension.

Comment: alert? `alert($( ".next" ).length);`, just to check if its empty

Comment: Okay, I have found why. I need to do:
    content.document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].click();

But then, how could I access content.document using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. In order to retrieve the DOM node I need to access content.document.

```
var theNode = content.document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].click();
$('.next', window.content.document).trigger('click');
```